# On logout/login Google plus iOS sdk asks permission for already granted user

Tags: ios, google-plus

I am using google plus iOS sdk for login in my app. When ever i logged out from g+ and try to login again it shows permission screen (both in G+ app and browser). I cannot use trysilentauthentication because my app supports login via facebook too. How can i configure my app requesting this only once?

Answer (score 0):

trySilentAuthentication is the correct answer there. If you are concerned about not giving the user the option to add Facebook to their existing Google sign in on your app, then set a flag with the result of trySilentAuthentication, and if that flag is Yes then don't immediately process the response to the finishedWithAuth:error - only do that on button press.

Comment: Hi Ian thanx for the reply. trySilentAuthentication wont work if the user signout from app. I do a lot of research and find similar apps such as tripit where google plus  login behaves as above said manner. Can u suggest any app which bypass this permission screen

Comment: If the user signs out they have to re-consent unfortunately. Take a look at an app like Fancy for a good implementation.

Comment: Actually i am looking for a workaround for the consent screen after signout, Now realize it is impossible. Thanx for the help.

Comment: @lan after logout of google+ and again clicked on login througn googleplus its not opening the login page is there any reason?

Comment: @Arunakumari - probably best to ask a new question with example code